# How can I print out code that has indents to actually have the indents?

Tags: java, printing

I need to print out code, and have the indentation be correct but its all printing right at the beginning of the line.

```
public static void printData(Scanner fileScanner) {

        int lineNumber = 0;

        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {

            System.out.println(lineNumber + ":    " + fileScanner.nextLine());

            lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + "Cross-Reference Index");
```

}

This prints out all the code starting at the beginning of the line, but i'd like it to look formatted like actual code..

Comment: Do you mean you want to take a file that is unformatted/poorly formatted code and do all of the correct formatting (with adding a line number on front)?

Comment: I supposed the requirement was just to output the lines as they are in the input (with line numbers), but leading whitespace is getting lost.

Comment: Sorry, the line number has nothing to do with it, its just one of the requirements for the assignment. but hes giving us a java file, and we need to take that java file, and print it out as it is in his file

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is probably the wrong tool for the job.  The main point of Scanner is to split input into 'tokens', typically delimited by whitespace.   Sounds like even nextLine skips leading whitespace.

Try using [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Incidentally, you'll probably want to make your line-number field fixed-width.  Try

```
  String.format("%-7d:", lineNumber);
```

which will result in the number being left-justified, padded with spaces to a width of 7, and then followed by colon.  (Making the prefix a multiple of 8 in length is advisable in case there are hard tabs)